# Mapstruct: Abstract source class error: No property named

Tags: mapstruct

I have an abstract class that I should map in a DTO using Mapstruct:

```
@Data    
public abstract class Car {
    private String color;
}

@Data
public class ElectricCar extends Car {
    private Double batteryCapacity;
}

@Data
public class FuelCar extends Car {
    private Double engineSize;
}

@Data
public class CarDto {
    private String color;
    private Double batteryCapacity;
    private Double engineSize;
}

@Mapper
public interface CarMapper {
    @Mapping( source = "batteryCapacity", target="battery")
    @Mapping( source = "engineSize", target="engine")
    CarDto toTarget(Car source);
}
```

The mapper will fail with error: error: No property named "batteryCapacity".

How can I make those fields optional so that they have a default value when there are not exiting in the source class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this particular example the new `SubclassMapping` will work.

e.g.

```java
@Mapper
public interface CarMapper {

    @SubclassMapping( target = CarDto.class, source = FuelCar.class)
    @SubclassMapping( target = CarDto.class, source = ElectricCar.class)
    CarDto toTarget(Car source);
}
```

As you can see there is no need to define specific `@Mapping` annotations since MapStruct will create implicit mappings between the different target types and the properties will be implicitly mapped.

Comment: Thanks a lot for you help and I'm really happy that the people that are developing/maintaining  Mapstruct are really active here :)
With @SubclassMapping it throws a Stackoverflow exception so I had to implement:
`CarDto toTarget(FuelCar source)` and `CarDto toTarget(ElectricCar source)` and then it worked

Comment: There shouldn't be a StackOverflow. Can you please create an issue in the MapStruct issue tracker, so we can have a look at it?